# Redux with React-Navigation nested navigators: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nextState.routes.forEach')...

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

Trying to get the navigation state in the redux store and having issues. I am close but trying to understand what this error means: 
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nextState.routes.forEach')

There is an authcheck in the navigation root render function that determines what navigation state to use. The right one is chosen but then when it attempts to use it I am hit with the error above.

Inside the AppNavigator are two different navigation routes that are separated as so.

```
-AppNavigator
--SignedInNavigator
---TabBar
--SignedOutNavigator
---StackNavigator
```

This is the navigation object being used when I get the error.

```
[exp] Object {
[exp]   "index": 0,
[exp]   "routes": Array [
[exp]     Object {
[exp]       "action": Object {
[exp]         "routeName": "Home",
[exp]         "type": "Navigation/NAVIGATE",
[exp]       },
[exp]       "key": "Init-id-1513449605995-1",
[exp]       "routeName": "SignedOut",
[exp]       "type": undefined,
[exp]     },
[exp]   ],
[exp] }

render() {
   const { navigationState, dispatch, isLoggedIn } = this.props;
   const state = isLoggedIn ? navigationState.stateForLoggedIn : navigationState.stateForLoggedOut;

   return (
       <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state })} />
   );
}
```

Can provide more code such as reducer being used if necessary. Only reason I am not is because the reducers are giving me the info I expect right now but clearly it is not being digested well. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am also new but this worked for me. Below are two separate files....

ReduxNavigation.js

```
    import React from 'react'
import * as ReactNavigation from 'react-navigation'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import AppNavigation from './AppNavigation'

// here is our redux-aware our smart component
function ReduxNavigation (props) {
  const { dispatch, nav } = props
  const navigation = ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers({
    dispatch,
    state: nav
  })

  return <AppNavigation navigation={navigation} />
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nav: state.nav })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation)
```

AppNavigation.js

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import { Animated, Easing } from 'react-native'
import LoginScreen from '../Containers/LoginScreen'
import LaunchScreen from '../Containers/LaunchScreen'
import HomeScreen from '../Containers/HomeScreen'
import SignUpScreen from '../Containers/SignUpScreen'
import SettingsScreen from '../Containers/SettingsScreen'
import VehicleCreateScreen from '../Containers/VehicleCreateScreen'
import styles from './Styles/NavigationStyles'

// Manifest of possible screens
const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator({
  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
  LaunchScreen: { screen: LaunchScreen },
  HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  SignUpScreen: { screen: SignUpScreen },
  SettingsScreen: { screen: SettingsScreen },
  VehicleCreateScreen: { screen: VehicleCreateScreen }
}, {
    // Default config for all screens
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'LaunchScreen',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: styles.header
    },
    transitionSpec: {
      duration: 0,
      timing: Animated.timing,
      easing: Easing.step0,
    },
  },

  transitionConfig = () => ({
  }),


)

export default PrimaryNav
```

Comment: Ended up shelving my changes for now. I think my main issue is that I have two different navigators that go on the top stacknavigator. I don't think the navigation tree is getting built as expected. If I put all the screens on the top level stacknavigator it works but then there are issues with authing the user and keeping the screen navigators separate. I think I will have to change more of the structure to get the functionality I want.